# KL divergence vs cross entropy

Tags: classification

I have a binary Image classification problem and use a deep learning model for classification problems. In general, we use the cross-entropy loss for this but I would like to use kl-divergence as a loss function. Can you use it or not? If not why can't I use it as I get probabilities at the output softmax layer of the model

Any kind of reference is helpful

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use it, pytorch has an existing loss function for this, see [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.KLDivLoss.html). I can not comment on the effectiveness of using KL divergence as a loss function over cross entropy loss as I haven't used it myself.

Comment: KL(P_0 || Q_0)+KL(P_1 || Q_1)  where P_0 implies actual probability(soft label) , Q_0 implies predicted probability for class 0  and P_1, Q_1 is for class 1. Im trying this way. Is it right or it is not the way to use.